# Combine single array of objects by unique attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, arrayobject

I have an array of object, which has be combined based on a unique attribute.
For example:

```
[
  { "macId": "123", "input": 30},
  { "macId": "567", "input": 40},
  { "macId": "123", "power": 100},
  { "macId": "567", "power": 250}
]
```

I want the resultant array of object as the following:

```
[
  { "macId": "123", "input": 30, "power": 100},
  { "macId": "567", "input": 40 "power": 250}
]
```

Is this possible with *lodash*? If not, how can I write a short code for this to do so?

Comment: I'm almost sure you can do something with `Array.reduce` and some algorithm

Comment: Have look at lodash's [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge)

Comment: Just a reminder @chetanraj. There are multiple answers here which answer your question. I suggest you pick one as the accepted answer so we can mark this as solved. (Or if you don't think this question is solved,  maybe you could clarify how the answers misunderstand your question, so that others can try to answer your question with this new information in mind).

Answer (score 2):

Using lodash I would try [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) using `macId`, then using [`merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) to "combine" the objects in the resulting array.

```
const after = 
  _(before)
    .groupBy('macId')
    .map(group => _.merge(...group))
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in combination with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const arr = [
    { "macId": "123", "input": 30},
    { "macId": "567", "input": 40},
    { "macId": "123", "power": 100},
    { "macId": "567", "power": 250}
]

const result = [...arr.reduce((acc, obj) =>
    acc.set(obj.macId, Object.assign(acc.get(obj.macId) || {}, obj)), new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, with [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) :

```
var myMergedArray = arr.reduce((acc = [], val) => {
  if (acc.filter(obj => obj.macId === val.macId).length !== 0) {
    Object.assign(acc.find((el) => el.macId === val.macId), val)
  } else {
    acc.push(val);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
```

Snippet :

```js
var arr = [
  { "macId": "123", "input": 30},
  { "macId": "567", "input": 40},
  { "macId": "123", "power": 100},
  { "macId": "567", "power": 250}
]

var myMergedArray = arr.reduce((acc = [], val) => {
  if (acc.filter(obj => obj.macId === val.macId).length !== 0) {
    Object.assign(acc.find((el) => el.macId === val.macId), val)
  } else {
    acc.push(val);
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(myMergedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `lodash` you can easily group it and map it back (merge using reduce or _.merge) easily.

```js
var arr = [
  { "macId": "123", "input": 30},
  { "macId": "567", "input": 40},
  { "macId": "123", "power": 100},
  { "macId": "567", "power": 250}
]

var unique = _.chain(arr).groupBy('macId').map(v => _.merge(...v)).value();

console.log(unique)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```